# how to make a get request to a url inside django view and return the response?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

without using `serializer_class` and `queryset` properties inside viewclass(which inherits `viewsets.ModelViewSet`) ;

i want to make a get request to a another url and return its response as the result of django  get request.

can we do that?

Thanks.

Comment: are you using django-rest-framework?

Comment: Is `urllib` what you need?

Comment: @whale_steward yes, i am using  django rest framework..

Comment: @shellbye when i use urllib or python-requests , i get the following error

`base_name` argument not specified, and could not automatically determine the name from the viewset, as it does not have a `.queryset` attribute.

apart from this, it also asks for 'serializer_class'  attribute.

but what i require is, making a get request to another webservice and return its json reply(reply.json) as the response in my django api by doing 
return Response(reply.json)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put any dummy model and make it work.

```
class SampleViewSet(APIView):
    model = DummyModel
    renderer_classes = (JSONRenderer,)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       if request.method == "GET":

        // do some operation

        return Response(<json response>, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```